# iDevice native headphones button function change

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, avaudioplayer, headphones

I have and app with AVAudioPlayer. And I want to change headphone button functions from "volume up / volume down" to "play-pause / forward". Is it possible?
Looking for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functionality you are looking to achieve cannot be performed by Apple Documented APIs